# ndepend, .net assemblies enabled

Tags: ndepend

In tools -> options -> .NET Assemblies Enabled, it is possible to temporarily disable framework assemblies such as mscorlib and system. Is there anyway to do this on a per project basis such that the settings are persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framework/Third-Party assemblies are inferred automatically each time you open the *NDepend Project Properties panel*. So you can still discard them manually from thye .ndproj file XML content, but they'll come back when you open the *NDepend Project Properties panel*. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I'm not interested in the dependencies involved. Its a pain point manually removing them each time. They especially add clutter to the dependency graph.

Comment: You have the option "Project Properties > Report > Graph > Hide Third-Party Assemblies" for that.   Also, in the Graph panel, you have the menu "Reset to Application Assemblies only"